# javascript sum value in loop group by attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 types of rows (Basic and Extra). I need SUM of input values group by attribute "data-type"

```
<div class="row-item" data-type="Basic"><input type="number" value="2" class="number-input"></div>
<div class="row-item" data-type="Basic"><input type="number" value="5" class="number-input"></div>
<div class="row-item" data-type="Basic"><input type="number" value="3" class="number-input"></div>
<div class="row-item" data-type="Basic"><input type="number" value="4" class="number-input"></div>
<div class="row-item" data-type="Extra"><input type="number" value="3" class="number-input"></div>
<div class="row-item" data-type="Extra"><input type="number" value="5" class="number-input"></div>
```

and I need i.e object of arrays:

```
Basic => sum : 14,
Extra => sum : 8
```

I tried something but it does not works ...

```
data = {};
$(".row-item").each(function (index, elem) {

    var type = $(elem).data('type');
    count = $(elem).find(".number-input").val();
    sum += count;

    data[type] = {
        sum: sum
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach would be the following. This would also allow you to have more types if need be.

```js
var data = {};
$(".row-item").each(function(index, elem) {

  var type = $(elem).data('type');
  var count = parseInt( $(elem).find(".number-input").val(), 10 );
  if (data.hasOwnProperty(type)) {
    data[type]["sum"] += count;
  } else {
    data[type] = {"sum": count};
  }
});
alert (JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
//console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row-item" data-type="Basic"><input type="number" value="2" class="number-input"></div>
<div class="row-item" data-type="Basic"><input type="number" value="5" class="number-input"></div>
<div class="row-item" data-type="Basic"><input type="number" value="3" class="number-input"></div>
<div class="row-item" data-type="Basic"><input type="number" value="4" class="number-input"></div>
<div class="row-item" data-type="Extra"><input type="number" value="3" class="number-input"></div>
<div class="row-item" data-type="Extra"><input type="number" value="5" class="number-input"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `data-type` values in selector to select specific value.

```
var basic = 0;
$('.row-item[data-type="Basic"]').each(function () {
    basic += parseInt($(this).find('input').val(), 10) || 0;
});


var extra = 0;
$('.row-item[data-type="Extra"]').each(function () {
    extra += parseInt($(this).find('input').val(), 10) || 0;
});

alert(basic + ' ' + extra);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/773va00j/

**EDIT**

```
var obj = {
    Basic: 0,
    Extra: 0
};

$('.row-item[data-type]').each(function () {
    obj[$(this).data('type')] += parseInt($(this).find('input.number-input').val(), 10);
});

console.log('Basic ' + obj.Basic);
console.log('Extra ' + obj.Extra);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/773va00j/1/

Comment: yes I know, but I want cleaner solution in one loop becase this is only example and "data-type" values can be more